# Branch io dont open ios app

Tags: ios, branch.io

Is there a way i can configure branch link not to open ios app even if it installed on the device and redirect to my website. Keep in mind this is only for some cases where i dont want to open the app

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: yes, this is possible! Just set the `$web_only` control parameter to `true` when creating the link in question.

Full documentation [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/#web-only-links).